# useQuery does not trigger when a variable in input object is set to undefined or empty string

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a query that takes input params, say date

```
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_LIST, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        date: date,
      },
    },
  });
```

```
export const GET_LIST = gql`
  query list($input: ListParams) {
    list(input: $input) {
      totalCount
      recordCount
      list {
        listId
        date
        qty
        amount
        currency
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

```
input ListParams {
  date: String
}
```

I need to fetch the list, where the user can filter based on date. Now on initial load, date is not set, query is called. The user sets a date, no issues, the query is called again with the the date value, now when the user removes the date filter, the date value becomes undefined, and I would expect useQuery to be called again with no variables this time, but it is never called.

I have tried setting empty string as well, even then useQuery does not get called which is not the intended behaviour

```
 input: {
        date: date||'',
      },
```

Answer (score 5):

Apollo-Cilent has a cache mechanism when query variable you pass into the useQuery hook is the same to a previous value.

Doc:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/
Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/usequery-example-apollo-client3-dx626

You can solve this by either using a refetch or polling mechanism built into the useQuery hook:

```js
function Date({ date }) {

const { loading, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_LIST, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        date: date,
      },
    },
  });
//...
return (<div>
      <Component data={data} onDateChange={() => refetch()}/>
    </div>)
}
```

Or, if having the empty/undefined variable in the query doesn't specific purpose, you should probably not render the component by adding `{!input.date && <Date /> }` or not sending any query by adding `skip` variable in your useQuery hook:

```js
const { loading, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_LIST, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        date: date,
      },
    },
    skip: !input?.date // <------ Skip the query when input.date is missing or empty
  });
```

Late answer (I think you have probably resolved this issue), I am writing some notes here in case someone else runs into this problem.